# Calling IAsyncEnumerable<string> before other methods

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task, iasyncenumerable

Good day guys,
Please I'm trying to read all file paths in a folder using `IAsyncEnumerable`, based on a library that I'm using. I've been able to create a method for that, but the challenge I have is that, the library method

```
StartQueryingFromFiles(IAsyncEnumerable<string> files, CancellationToken token)
```

is called first, before calling the `IAsyncEnumerable`. Hence the values are always null.

What can I do to ensure that my parameter is not null. Please check my code below:

```
    private void btnStarts_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, Label searchLabel, TabPage page, ProgressBar bar)
    {
        try
        {
            bar.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
            var searchPath = searchLabel.Text; //Path to folder
            var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var bolFinished = false;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchPath) && Directory.Exists(searchPath))
            {
                Task.Run(() =>
                {   
                    //The method below gets called first before the iteration                     
                    StartQueryingFromFiles(FetchAllItems(searchPath), tokenSource.Token);
                    bolFinished = true;
                });
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No Audio Files Found.");
            }

            if(bolFinished)
                bar.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Blocks;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    //This gets called first, its supposed to return all files, but returns nothing
    IAsyncEnumerable<string> FetchAllItems(string searchPath)
    {
        return FetchItems(searchPath);
    }

    //This is called last, I don't know why. It reads the file paths in the folder
    async IAsyncEnumerable<string> FetchItems(string searchPath)
    {
        foreach (var item in Directory.EnumerateFiles(searchPath))
        {
            await Task.Delay(100);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()} Reading: {item}");
            yield return item;
        }
    }
```

Edit:
Added the StartQueryingFromFiles method

```
    public void StartQueryingFromFiles(IAsyncEnumerable<string> files, CancellationToken token)
    {
        _ = QueryCommandBuilder.Instance
            .BuildRealtimeQueryCommand()
            .From(files, MediaType.Audio)
            .WithRealtimeQueryConfig(config =>
            {
        // provide a success callback that will be invoked for matches that pass result entry filter
        config.SuccessCallback = result =>
                {
                    foreach (var entry in result.ResultEntries)
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Successfully matched {entry.TrackId}");
                    }
                };

        // configure result entry filter
        config.ResultEntryFilter = new TrackMatchLengthEntryFilter(5d);
                return config;
            })
            .UsingServices(modelService, mediaService)
            .Query(token);
    }
```

You can get more information about the library here: https://github.com/AddictedCS/soundfingerprinting/wiki/Realtime-Query-Command#query-from-a-continuous-stream-of-files

Thanks

Comment: Could you include the `StartQueryingFromFiles` method?

Comment: Thanks @TheodorZoulias, I will edit and include it now. Thanks

Comment: This code could really benefit from an `async`  arrangement, as in `await FetchAllItems(searchPath)`

Comment: Thanks @RobertHarvey, if you make FetchAllItems an async await, then it will not return all items, it will be returning the item one after the other. Even though in my case, its not continuous. I only get one item, by this time nothing is passed to the StartQueryingFromFiles method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so after a lot of researching, kudos to this guys : https://www.dotnetcurry.com/csharp/async-streams

I was able to see that I could use System.Linq.Async to get my files to be converted to IAsyncEnumerable.

Hence instead of writting all those FetchItems methods above, no need.
All I needed was do the below:

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
     DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(searchPath);
     var getAllFiles = di.GetFiles()
           .Where(file => file.Name.EndsWith(".mp3"))
           .Select(file => file.Name).ToAsyncEnumerable<string>();

      StartQueryingFromFiles(getAllFiles, tokenSource.Token);
      bolFinished = true;
  });
```

Hence being able to get all the files into one IAsyncEnumerable.